# Выход из цикла при нажатии ESC

Tags: циклы, c++

Хочу сделать выход из цикла по нажатию клавиши ESC.
Пробую сделать выход из цикла как написано здесь: 
  [How to read until ESC button is pressed from cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214753/how-to-read-until-esc-button-is-pressed-from-cin-in-c)

```
char choose;
    while(true)
    {
    cout << "Выберите способ сортировки - по начальному пункту (s), по конечному пункту (e), по номер маршрута (n): ";
    cin >> choose;

    if(choose == 27) break;

    switch(choose){
    case 's': {SortRoutesByStartPoint(routeList, n); ShowRoutes(routeList, n, "Отсортированный список маршрутов (по начальной точке):"); break;}
    case 'e': {SortRoutesByEndPoint(routeList, n); ShowRoutes(routeList, n, "Отсортированный список маршрутов (по конечной точке):"); break;}
    case 'n': {SortRoutesByNumber(routeList, n); ShowRoutes(routeList, n, "Отсортированный список маршрутов (по номеру маршрута):"); break;}
    default: {cout << "Нет такой сортировки\n\n"; break;}
    }
}
```

но не работает. Как можно заставить выход из цикла работать по нажатию ESC?

Answer (score 3):

Всё ведь работает, только после нажатия Esc нужно начать Enter, так как считывается не символ, а строка до "\n".

Можно использоваться функцией getch из conio.h в венде или вот такой реализацией под linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int mygetch( )
{
    struct termios oldt, newt;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt );
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt );
    return ch;
}
```

Тогда код

```
choose = mygetch();
if(choose == 27) break;
```

отлично работает.